# How to approach texture painting images such as faces?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am trying to figure out the best way to texture paint complex images on models. For example, I am trying to texture paint a face on a cartoon character, but I've realised there's pretty much only a brush (and line) option. I can't seem to easily paint shapes as you could in photoshop (e.g. draw a 'perfect' circle). I've looked into simply making the texture in photoshop and then importing it back into blender, but doing that means I won't be able to actively see the changes I'm making on the 3D model, which is too difficult for me as a beginner.

Comment: Hello, you can draw a perfect circle in Blender, but of course Blender will never be as convenient as Photoshop or other image editors for editing images and painting

Comment: Awesome, how can I do this? Is there a draw circle tool? If there is it's very hidden...

Comment: I would put a circular alpha in the Texture Mask section of the painting tools tab. Then I'd change the fall of until I had the look i was going for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you outline how I'd go about creating a circular alpha? I'm fairly new to blender and I'm finding it hard to pick things up even using tutorials and things. @ZackBowen

Comment: No problem! An alpha is just a black and white image. You can make them in Blender , but is easier to do in any image editor like Photoshop or even Paint. Just make the shape your looking for in white with either a black or transparent background. Then save that as a PNG, and there you have your alpha! Alternatively you could google free circular alpha textures and download one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For painting, Blender will never be as good as an image editor like Photoshop, Gimp or Krita, a solution would be to use imported textures, but for example for a perfect circle you just need to edit the *Falloff* profile:

[image]